# How to color some words in differents lines in the RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I'm in trouble, today I tried to color some diffents words in differents lines clicked on a button. Can You explain me how to do this? I was able to do only this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    richTextBox1.Select(int start , int length); //It's wrong but It explains How to use .Select if you know start and length...
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

But how can I work on a line I know the number of, having already the text into the RichTextBox?
Thanks.

Comment: `richTextBox1.Select(int start , int length);` ?

Comment: Did you try this (he is doing by changing raw RTF )http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/RTFSyntaxColour.aspx

Comment: What do you mean _"a determinated line"_? The code you've written is the way to do it. Are you trying to color a line you know the number of?

Comment: @L.B It's what have you to write when you use .Select , it's an "example" ...

Comment: Then you need to define what you call a _line_ => Are lines separated by `\n`? Or do you have no horizontal scrollbar on your `richTextBox` and lines depends on the width of your `richTextBox`?

Comment: Having gone the `Select()` & `SelectionColor` route myself.  I can tell you this.  It's dog slow.  You'll be much better off following what @SSamra linked to and formatting the raw RTF yourself.

Comment: @Otiel No, the lines are separated by \n...

Comment: @Fuex when I used the approach you've shown I could only load ~500 lines into the RichTextBox before performance became an issue.  Using RTF formatting I can load thousands of lines in an instant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If lines are separated by `\n`, your problem is then to count the number of `\n` characters before getting to the wanted line.

For that, you can use an extension method:

```
public static int NthIndexOf(this String str, String match, int occurence) {
    int i = 1;
    int index = 0;

    while (i <= occurence && ( index = str.IndexOf(match, index + 1) ) != -1) {

        if (i == occurence) {
            // Occurence match found!

            return index;
        }
        i++;
    }

    // Match not found
    return -1;
}
```

Now, you can find `start` and `end` values to color the selection:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int lineNb = 13; // I assume you get this value initialized somewhere, 
                     // I wrote 13 for the example
    int start = richTextBox1.Text.NthIndexOf("\n", lineNb);
    int length = richTextBox1.Text.NthIndexOf("\n", lineNb + 1);
    richTextBox1.Select(start , length);
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
}
```